# Plot non-polynomial multivariate implicit equation

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, plot, graph

I am currently trying to plot the following equation with matplotlib:

```
-4xy + x² - y² + 4(x³y - xy³) = 0
```

I do not want to solve this awful equation in order to plot it by simply assigning `x = np.linspace(-5,5)` and then putting it into my equation.

I am wondering if is possible to plot the solution directly with `matplotlib.pyplot`? I am able to plot the function well and quickly using Geogebra, so I imagine that this should also be possible using python. However, I have not found any other questions about this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by 'Geogebra is doing that'?. What exactly does it do? Usually if a program plots a function there is no way around evaluating the function for all values x and y to plot the surface.

Comment: If you write "4x³ y + x² - 4x y³ - 4x y - y² = 0" in the Geogebra input, it will plot the corresponding solution lines.

Comment: I see. Under the hood it will definitely evaluate the values and then plot. What you can try doing is creating a function that takes the definition of a function and then plots it for you right away, but you won't get around evaluating the function. How else is the computer supposed to know where to plot things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is using Sympy's [`plot_implicit`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html#sympy.plotting.plot_implicit.plot_implicit) function.

**Code:**

```
from sympy import plot_implicit, symbols, Eq

x, y = symbols('x y')

plot_implicit(Eq(-4*x*y+x**2-y**2+4*(x**3-x*y**3), 0),
              adaptive=False,
              points=1000)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Under the hood, this uses a mesh-grid to decide whether to plot the function at every point on the graph. This is what Geogebra will be doing under the hood as well. To apply this approach in vanilla matplotlib, we can use a contour plot:

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Plot axes in middle
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

# Set up mesh grid
x = y = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

# Plot contour
ax.contour(X, Y, -4*X*Y+X**2-Y**2+4*(X**3-x*Y**3), [0])
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]